# AngularJS advanced sanitization of content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking to build an editor that allows users to leverage html and angularjs directives but restricts attributes that I deem unsafe.

My first attempt was to use $sanitize but this prevents me from using directives within the input.

**Sample Input**

```
<p style="font-weight: bold;" onmouseover="window.alert('oops');">
    Test
</p>
<div hello-world></div>
<script>window.alert('test')</script>
```

**$Sanitize Output**

```
<p>Test</p>    
<div></div>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<p>Test</p>
<div hello-world></div>
```

Comment: could you elaborate here in this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/gdAx7IYg1mdHsQM6fHbl?p=preview..looks ok for me

Comment: The <script></script> tag wasn't removed and the onmouseover attribute is still present, meaning the author is allowed to author JS. The only scripts I want to permit are those enabled by angular directives.